# image rollovers with text appearing elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rollover

this old page here is done with jQuery and works OK, but the text at the bottom is done using an image. Now I'd really like that to be real text.

http://ou812.bplaced.net/rollover-with-text/

I apologize because I know there are loads of discussions a bit like this, but hours and hours of searching didn't help. I'm no Javascript or CSS crack. Can someone point me in the right direction? An example page?

Many thanks!

Comment: you can use something like on hover and then set the text of the box depending what you're hovering over. All easily achieved with jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2d2m/)**

You can do something like this (please note that this is bare minimal):

HTML:

```
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
<p></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    p   = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

for(i = 0; i < div.length; i++)
{
    div[i].onmouseover = function(){
        p.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

No need for jQuery for this, but if you want to use it, here it is.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2d2m/1/)**

```
var div = $('div');
var p   = $('p');

$(div).hover(function(){
    $(p).html($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So I just need to work out how to hide the text inside the divs, or to be more precise, show a rollover image in its place, right?